# Finding the Pointwise limit of $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{n}$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Im trying the find the pointwise limit of a sequence on $[0,1]$ to determine if the sequence converges.
My sequence is below.
$$f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{n}$$

I know that for the sequence to converge $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$.
But I don't understand the difference between $f_n(x)$ and $f(x)$.
Can someone point out the approach i need to take ?

Comment: write $f_1(x)$, $f_2(x)$ and $f_3(x)$, and imagine this sequence of functions going on. Where does it go to ?

Answer (score 1):

The $f_n$s are given - the function $f$ is something which may or may not exist (the *limit* of the sequence of $f_n$s). The question is basically asking, "Is it the case that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)$$ exists for all $x$?"

If this limit *does* already exist for each $x$, call the value of the limit "$f(x)$" - then this $f$ is the limit of the sequence $f_n$. For example, if $g_n(x)={1\over n}x$, then it's clear that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} g_n(x)=0$ for all $x$ - so the sequence of functions $g_n$ would converge to the function $g(x)=0$.

If this limit *does not* exist, for some $x$, then the sequence of functions $f_n$ does not converge (in the pointwise sense; there are other senses of convergence one might be interested in, but that's another question).